# jquery json ie8 and lower not updating script

Tags: jquery, json, internet-explorer-8

I'm having an issue where my json script is not updating on ie8 and lower.

I guess its a caching problem. How would i go about fixing this?

This is the page where it is running.
http://www.roofracks.co.uk/thule/Roof+Mounted+Bikes+and+Cycles+Racks+and+Carriers/533.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#preloader').ajaxStart(function(){
    $(this).show();}).ajaxStop(function(){
    $(this).hide();
});     
    $.post('http://www.roofracks.co.uk/template_load/get_dynamic_prices.php', $("#productPrice").serialize(),
        function(data){
            $('input[id=productID]').val(data.productID);
            $('input[id=productDescription]').val(data.productDescription);
            $('input[id=productPrice]').val(data.productPrice);
            $('.productSinglePrice').html(data.productSinglePrice);
            $('input[id=productThumb]').val(data.productThumb);
            $('input[id=productThumbLarge]').val(data.productThumbLarge);
        },'json');
    $("#productPrice").change(function(){
        $('.productSinglePrice').empty();
        $.post('http://www.roofracks.co.uk/template_load/get_dynamic_prices.php', $("#productPrice").serialize(),
            function(data){
                $('input[id=productID]').val(data.productID);
                $('input[id=productDescription]').val(data.productDescription);
                $('input[id=productPrice]').val(data.productPrice);
                $('.productSinglePrice').html(data.productSinglePrice);
                $('input[id=productThumb]').val(data.productThumb);
                $('input[id=productThumbLarge]').val(data.productThumbLarge);
        },'json');
        return false;

            });                         
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two kinds of caching problems you could be having.

IE is caching the script itself, so changes aren't being reflected. To fix this, add a parameter with the current date/time to your `<script>` tag, like so:

```
<script src="js/myscript.js?201202291038"></script>
```

IE is caching the AJAX requests. To fix this, set the `cache` option to `false` using the `$.ajaxSetup()` function, like so:

```
$.ajaxSetup({cache: false});
```

Comment: I have tried both. Seems its not working

    <?php 
 $date = time();
 ?>
    <script src="http://www.roofracks.co.uk/template_load/js/e-script.js?<?php echo $date; ?>"></script>

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest doing what **Anthony Grist** posted. Also, I think your code could be a lot DRYer. I haven't tested this but you get the idea...

```
function(data) {

    var ids = ['#productID',
                '#productDescription',
                '#productPrice',
                '#productThumb',
                '#productThumbLarge'];

    for (var i = 0, len = ids.length; i < len; i++) {
        $(ids[i]).val(data[ids[i].match(/[^#]+/)]);
    }

    $('.productSinglePrice').html(data.productSinglePrice);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the post, i'm very new to jquery so i dont understand this coding to much. Ill have to study up on the coding first :)